# How to switch terminal to full screen in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

Is there a way to go full screen with Terminal in Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal supports full screen mode in Lion, but not Snow Leopard.

I believe that [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/)'s full screen mode does support Snow Leopard though.

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> simultaneously, it'll switch between *full screen* and a *normal mode*.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Resize it to fit the screen
2. Change the font size to make it more comfortable
3. Change the startup size in Terminals' preference to fit what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Press the Green '+' and it'll go full screen. You'll still see your Dock and the Bar at the top though.